# How can I get the exact memory address on HDD of an file?

Tags: python

I'm going to make a kind of remover that erase files never recoverable.

I don't know the algorithm but I think it is possible to get exact file memory address and

write something like 'null' at there. So I'm searching at os module and others,

but don't know how to do that...Is there a function or the otherway?

Or what I have to do is just read the file binarymode and override it null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you entirely control the system, I think you'd be better off abandoning this particular pursuit.  Modern filesystems or mediums (e.g. SSD wear-leveling) can result in data being retained physically on-disk even if you overwrite them in-place.

Best practice in my book is to fill the disk with random data, then exclusively use whole-disk encryption.